# anaconda navigator crashes after some time after opening

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

when I open the anaconda navigator it remains open for some time (approx 30 to 40 seconds) and then crashes.
sometimes it also becomes  non responsive and then crashes. what do I have to do to solve this?

Comment: Is this related to this previous question of yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61186699/installed-and-then-wanted-to-open-the-anaconda-navigator-on-my-laptop ? We're going to need far more information than this.

Comment: yes it is, so i uninstalled anaconda and reinstalled it. it opens up to the screen where the checkbox of "help improve anaconda " appears. and then it crashes after i click "ok" or sometimes even before that